# Groovy cannot parse String to Date

Tags: date, grails, groovy

I want to parse `String` to `Date` using Groovy.

But I cannot parse to following `java.lang.String` to `Date`.

My code is like below.

```
import groovy.time.*

def date = new Date.parse("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy", "Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015")
```

But I get errors like below:

```
Unparseable date: "Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015". Stacktrace follows:
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

How can I parse it?

Comment: But is your entry data `Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015`? Is this coming from a form or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate `Locale`:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US)

def date = Date.parse("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", "Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015")
```

Other mistakes are `dd` instead of `d` and `Z` instead of `z`.

Comment: It seems worked, thank you! But, the result is "Fri Aug 28 21:28:48 JST 2015" instead of "Fri Aug 28 21:28:48 +0000 2015"

Comment: also don't forget to set the locale back to what you need. i'd rather use a `SimpleDateFormat` with the proper locale set there instead instead of meddling with global state in that case.

Comment: @saw303 if it's static, then no `new` operator is required as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is the oddly named [`Date.parseToStringDate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parseToStringDate%28java.lang.String%29) which takes this format and is locale agnostic:

```
groovy:000> Date.parse("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", "Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015")
Unparseable date: "Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015"
groovy:000> Date.parseToStringDate("Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015")
===> Fri Aug 28 13:12:11 CEST 2015
groovy:000> Locale.default
===> ja
groovy:000> Locale.default = Locale.US
===> en_US
groovy:000> Date.parse("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", "Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015")
===> Fri Aug 28 13:12:11 CEST 2015
groovy:000> Date.parseToStringDate("Fri Aug 28 11:12:11 +0000 2015")
===> Fri Aug 28 13:12:11 CEST 2015
```